# sending page URL with form asp

Tags: asp.net, webforms

What I'm trying to do is to send the a form with the page url in it.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbAutContactSubject" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="text" onblur="if(this.value=='Page.Title') this.value=this.defaultValue;" onfocus="if(this.defaultValue==this.value) this.value = 'Request.Url.AbsoluteUri';" />
```

I am new to asp, i figured if i could just get the subjects onfocus to display the page url (dont even know if you can do that) it would be a start.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current page's URL via JavaScript, like this:

```
window.location.href
```

You can also redirect the browser to a URL by setting the `window.location.href` property, like this:

```
window.location.href = "YourPage.aspx";
```